# How do I use serde to serialize a HashMap with non-serializable keys?

Tags: rust, serde

I have a `HashMap` as a value in a struct that I'm manually serializing:

```
pub struct GitInfo {
    pub branches: HashMap<Oid, Branch>,
}
```

`Branch` is something I've defined, but [`Oid`](https://docs.rs/git2/0.6.4/git2/struct.Oid.html) is an external type I don't own, with a `to_string()` method I'd be happy to use...

I've read [How do I use Serde to serialize a HashMap with structs as keys to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276896/how-do-i-use-serde-to-serialize-a-hashmap-with-structs-as-keys-to-json) but it refers to keys the author defined - I can't implement `Serialize` for `Oid` as it's not in my crate.  And I can't implement `Serialize` for `HashMap<Oid, Branch>` for similar reasons.

Is there some way around this?  I could build a wrapper struct around `HashMap<Oid, Branch>` but that seems like overkill.

It was suggested that I look at [How to transform fields during serialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383809/how-to-transform-fields-during-serialization-using-serde) or [How can I implement Serialize using an existing Display trait implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103801/how-can-i-implement-serialize-using-an-existing-display-trait-implementation) - both seem to boil down to using `serialize_with` - which I could possibly do, but I'd have to use the `derive(Serialize)` macro, when I was planning to serialize `GitInfo` manually (see below).  Or I could use a wrapper object.

If those are the only options, I could live with it, but it seems a bit surprising that there isn't a simpler way - is there some way to call a function like the `serialize_with` macro uses, but from within my `GitInfo` serialization?

Something like:

```
impl Serialize for GitInfo {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut state = serializer.serialize_struct("GitInfo", 2)?;
        state.serialize_field("other bits", &self.other_bits)?;
        state.serialize_field("branches", /* something */)?;
        state.end()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `serialize_field` instead of `serialize_map`?

Comment: I'm serializing a struct, `GitInfo`, with a field which is a `HashMap`.  So I'm using `serialize_struct` which returns a `SerializeStruct` which has no `serialize_map` method.

If there is some way to call `serialize_map` to make a new serialized version of the map, and then insert the results as a parameter to `serialize_field`, that'd be awesome - but I haven't found a way to do that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build a wrapper struct around `HashMap<Oid, Branch>` when storing it within your `GitInfo` struct, but you will need to use a wrapper struct when serializing the `HashMap` in a custom manner. You can define the new wrapper struct within your `Serialize` implementation to indicate that it should only be used for serialization.

```rust
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        struct Branches<'a>(&'a HashMap<Oid, Branch>);

        impl Serialize for Branches<'_> {
            fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
            where
                S: Serializer,
            {
                let mut map = serializer.serialize_map(Some(self.0.len()))?;
                for (oid, branch) in self.0 {
                    map.serialize_entry(&oid.to_string(), &branch)?;
                }
                map.end()
            }
        }

        let mut state = serializer.serialize_struct("GitInfo", 2)?;
        state.serialize_field("branches", &Branches(&self.branches))?;
        state.serialize_field("other bits", &self.other_bits)?;
        state.end()
    }
}
```

Here is a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c340b956b9b1b7c4093f22848e7b593c) showing a basic implementation of this solution.

Note that the code generated by [`serialize_with`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#serialize_with) follows this same pattern: it defines a newtype wrapper struct along with a `Serialize` implementation, and within that trait implementation it calls the function you provide.